# xml attribute tag value in JSON

Tags: java, json, xml

I am new to json. I have a data stored in xml file and I want to convert it to json. I could do that successfully. However, I am having a problem with the "attribute tag value"  e.g., in XML

```
<doc  ID="1">
```

The result should look like this:

```
 { 
    "doc": { 
       "@ID": "1", 
    "section": { 
         "@ID": "1",
         "words": [ 
            { 
                     "position": "456",
                     "word": "country",
                  ]
        }
        }
    }
```

However, I wasn't able to store the "@ID": "1" for "doc" and "section".

This is part of my code:

```
            JSONObject doc_obj = new JSONObject();   
            JSONObject  words_obj = new JSONObject();
            Map<String, String> words_Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            words_Map.put("position",  "456");
            words_Map.put("word",  "country");
            words_obj.put("words",words_Map); 
            doc_obj.put("doc",words_obj);
```

I couldnot find out how to assign the id to the doc and section.

Comment: JSON does not have attributes. I presume your programming language uses a `@` prefix to emulate them. Please edit the question and add tags with your programming language and/or framework.

Comment: I used online tool "http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html" so I got the converted xml to json with the @. I got the same result using my java program just I didn't know how to deal with the attributes which is very important to identify document by its id.